# ‘bundle’ No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, capistrano, rbenv

Im getting this weird bundle error when running

> cap production deploy

Command: cd /var/www/kingdoms/releases/20170202074830 && /usr/bin/env bundle check --path /var/www/kingdoms/shared/bundle

/usr/bin/env: 
‘bundle’
: No such file or directory

```
deploy@ip:~$ bundle --version

Bundler version 1.14.3

deploy@ip:~$ which bundle

/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to `require 'capistrano/rbenv'` in capfile

Comment: Add in the edited code so that no one else makes the same mistake.